# how to run get token while running the app with Visual studio and cache the token while using managed identity

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice, azure-identity

I have .net 6 web api application and this app is hosted as `Azure App Service` and I am using Azure Managed Identity option to retrieve token and using `Azure.Identity Version="1.7.0`

```
 var tokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
            new ManagedIdentityCredential("", new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                Retry =
                {
                    Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                    MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
                    MaxRetries = 5,
                    Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
                }
            }),
            new AzureCliCredential()
        );

        var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:Scope")?.Value }));
```

Currently I am only able to run this app as `Azure App Service` since identity of the app service is registered with Azure AD app and I am not seeing any out of the box solution to cache the token.

Please suggest to solve below 2 issues,

1. How to get token while I am running the web app within Visual Studio 2022 ?
2. Is there out of the box solution available to cache the token, if No then what are the options?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` configuration file?

Comment: just the scope `"AzureAd": {
    "Scope": "api://d39cb913-ef82-48ba-9b16-81800731a"
  }`